# MongoDB error while setting up ExtentX Server

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sails.js, extentreports, extent

I am trying to setting up ExtentX for ExtentReports. I am following the documentation properly.My mongogb is up and running. I unzipped the ExtentX server app and do npm install after that when I run sails lift it is showing error ad failed to connect to MongoDB even mongodb is up

Please Help!

```
[enter image description here][1]
```

Comment: any Answers????

Comment: Did you intend to add an image to question?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by upgrading windows to 64 bits